# Transaction email - I like to change the order detail fonts

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, css, email-templates

My goal is to have the Order Confirmation Email have a uniformed look. I am able to make changes the using the Transnational Email admin function in Magento but some parts of the Order Confirmation are not programmed in the HTML coding using the Transnational Email.
I have attached a copy of the final copy that is sent to our customer and i have inserted a copy of the Transnational Email html coding.
I'm looking to have the Logo moved to the center of the heading, and the line item font, look the same for total, sub total, shipping, and Grand total.

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
```

{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

## Thank you for your BIOTONE order.

Once your package ships you will receive an email with a link to track your order. Your order summary is below.

Order Questions?

{{depend store_phone}}
                            **Call:** 
                            {{var store_phone}}
                            {{/depend}}
                            {{depend store_hours}}
                            {{var store_hours}} PST (M-F)
                            **Closed Weekends and Holidays**
                            {{/depend}}
                            {{depend store_email}}
                            **Email:** {{var store_email}}
                            {{/depend}}

#### Your order #{{var order.increment_id}}

Placed on {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}

{{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            
                
                    {{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
                
            
            {{/if}}
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
            
                
                    
                        Bill to:

{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}

{{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    
                        Ship to:

{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}

{{/depend}}
                
                
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    
                        Shipping method:

{{var order.shipping_description}}

{{/depend}}
                    
                        Payment method:--

{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}